# Pushing array to firebase String Array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an existing table with data in firebase, it is just a simple string array and  not a object array. I want to add string array and push it to the firebase list array. I was thinking to loop through the string array and call the update function but is there a simpler way of doing it?

**Updating list in firebase:**

```
  let data = ["charamander", "mew", "onix"]
  await dataRef.update({
    list: firestoreFieldValue.arrayUnion(data)
  })
```

Firebase structure:
Collection -> Words (Doc) -> list
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Solution was spread operator**

```
  await dataRef.update({
        wordList: firestoreFieldValue.arrayUnion(...data)
      })
```